# Is there a function line 'pthread_cleanup_push' in Windows API?

Tags: winapi

In unix, there is functions named as 'pthread_cleanup_push' and 'pthread_cleanup_pop' to execute cleanup routine for resources or heap memory.

Is there such functions like them in Window API in this situation?

```
result = doSomething();
if (result = error) {
   CloseHandle(hSomething1);
   CloseHandle(hSomething2);
   ExitThread(GetLastError());
}
result = doNextStep();
if (result == anotherError) {
   // Redundant
   CloseHandle(hSomething1);
   CloseHandle(hSomething2);
   ExitThread(GetLastError());
}
result = doNextStep2();
if (result == anotherError) {
   // Redundant
   CloseHandle(hSomething1);
   CloseHandle(hSomething2);
   ExitThread(GetLastError());
}
```

Comment: for what you 3 time write the same block of code ?

Comment: In fact, I'm writing a socket program. I was intended to detect which step an error occurs(socket(), bind(), listen(),  accept(), and read/write()), and notify its position and its error code.

Comment: When an error occurs at one of the steps, the program should show the error code, close socket and release any related resources, and exit the thread. in this section, there is a redundancy

Comment: redundancy only as result of not best code. always possible avoid this. anyway any *pthread_cleanup_push* here unrelated and not help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you know once we call pthread_cleanup_push, the specified cleanup routine is automatically called when pthead_exit is called anywhere. I'd like to know if there is a similar function in WinAPI

Comment: my answer that you on wrong way. such functions unrelated to your problem and resources which you want cleanup - not per thread